# How does recurrence work in RNN's?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

So I am reading up on how RNN's are different from feed forward neural networks. I understand that it uses the time-1 during training. However it is not clear to me at what "level" this happens.

Does a RNN during the training of a sentence like "I am going out." Pass every word individually through the entire network before it evaluates the prediction or am I picturing this wrong? So does it:

1. Pass "I" through all layers of the network.
2. Save that output state as t
3. Pass "am" and t through all layers of the network.
4. Save that output state as t
5. Pass "going" and t through all layers of the network.
6. Save that output state as t
7. Pass "out" and t through all layers of the network.
8. Save that output state as t
9. Pass "." and t through all layers of the network.
10. Make a prediction
11. Evaluate prediction
12. Back propagation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea is right. When unrolled in time, the RNN looks like this

```
  I    am  going  out   .
  ↓     ↓    ↓     ↓    ↓
  █  →  █  → █  →  █  →  █ →  □
```

where █ is the recurrently applied function and □ is the classifier. The so-called back-propagation in time is nothing but pretending that the RNN is a very deep feed-forward network with the same layer repeated many times. Because the parameters in al the █ layers are the same, the gradient gets summed up.